# proxy_fcgi:error AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: ' - but ONLY when stepping with xdebug

Tags: php, apache, xdebug, fpm

Trying to debug a web page with Apache Netbeans IDE 12 and XDEBUG.

The page loads correctly outside the debug environment - but, when I enable XDEBUG via browser add-in (xdebug-helper):

- Netbeans stops correctly at First Line
- When I step to next statement, AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: '
  appears in Apache error log (but nothing beyond 'PHP Message: ')
- Browser displays blank screen, status 200, zero Content-Length
- Final lines of remote_xdebug log are:

  ```
      [346989] <- step_into -i 53
      [346989] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into"
  transaction_id="53" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
      [346989] Log closed at 2020-08-01 20:28:33
  ```
- Syslog has nothing related

**Where else can I look to figure out this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

Sigh...  I looked everywhere... except **kern.log**  And there it is:

```
php-fpm7.4[1540]: segfault at 2a ip 00007ff4a83f4d37 sp 00007ffc4945e550 error 4 in xdebug.so[7ff4a83e7000+29000]
```

A seg fault in xdebug

Comment: I'd be interested in figuring out what this is, so please file a bug report at https://bugs.xdebug.org, following the instructions on https://xdebug.org/reporting-bugs — try really hard to provide all the information asked for, please :-)